Getting ready state error when trying to upload. Suspect it might be htaccess rewrite issue?
I am trying to upload images. I have the following code working perfectly on another page, but it's not working here. I am getting this error when I try it  {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"} This page im working on has a .htaccess rewrite and im wondering if that might be the issue. Any advice would be appreciated.
RewriteRule ^new-listing listing.php?item=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
<form name="upload_media_form" id="upload_media_form" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="page_box stacked_lo image_preview_tray sortable" style="margin:40px auto 0 auto;">

        </div>

        <div class="sm_upload_btn_cont">
            <label style="" for="upload_media_file" class="btn_sm sm_upload_btn">ADD MEDIA</label>
        </div>

        <input type="file" id="upload_media_file" name="upload_media_file" hidden/>


    </form>



$('#upload_media_file').change(function() {
    $('#upload_media_form').submit();
});

$('#upload_media_form').on('submit',(function(e) {

var formData = new FormData(this);

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: '../functions/main_media_upload.php',
    data:formData,
    cache:false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType   : "JSON",
    success:function(data){

        if (data.error > 0) {

            alert(data.msg)

        } else if (data.error == 0) {
            alert(data.filename)
        }

        return false;

    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("Error - "+JSON.stringify(data))
        console.log("error");
        console.log(data);
        return false;
    }
});

}))


If the URL of the page is /new-listing (?), then what do you expect the relative URL ../functions/main_media_upload.php to resolve to in that context?

Im sorry im not following. Im still learning here. Can you let me know what you mean? Thank you!

You didn't say anything about any subfolders, so I am assuming your RewriteRule ^new-listing ... means, you are requesting this via a URL like http://localhost/new-listing. If that is the case - then what would the relative URL ../functions/main_media_upload.php be supposed to resolve to? )And if that isn't the case, then please clarify.)

I think it is related to the .htaccess rule.
You need to check the file paths in code and put correct directly for images uploading.
And you can rewrite rule in your local .htaccess file to exclude certain directories.

TY - im pretty inexperienced here. Could you show me an example of what I'd need to do? appreciate it

which file paths in the code are you referring to?
